# Why does vertical-align: baseline on buttons center them with respect to adjacent text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Consider this simple code:

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_element">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

I would have expected that the bottom of the button and the baseline of the text would coincide given that, by default, the `vertical-align` property of the button is `baseline`, but its button and the text seem to be centered with respect to a common line passing through them (which should have been the behavior achieved with `vertical-align: middle`)

Comment: FYI, there is no `vertical-align: center` there is only `vertical-align: middle`. Since buttons don't have baselines (only text does), I believe the decision was made to align the baseline of the surrounding text and the baseline of the button's text. It's only because the font sizes of the text and the buttons are so similar that `middle` and `baseline` look similar. I think if you changed the font size of the button to be considerably larger (or smaller), you would see the difference.

Comment: @HereticMonkey *Since buttons don't have baselines* --> I am not really sure about this. elements (inline or inline-block ones) in general have baseline that depend on the text inside them and other properties (like overflow)

Comment: We're getting into strange territory here. If you look at https://jsbin.com/jiqusuzoye/1/edit?html,css,output in Chrome and Firefox, you'll see that they treat the baseline of the button differently. IMO, my reading of the spec says that Firefox is correct (aligning the last line's baseline) and Chrome's behaviour is in error.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, I was a little loose with definitions there and meant to go back and edit, but didn't get there in 5 minutes. Buttons are special, since they have an internal box in which their contents are rendered (there's a SO answer about this I can't find right now). But essentially, the same calculation holds true; the baseline of the button is just below the center of the button (half the ex-height of the font specifically) for single lines of text.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - That really doesn't fit with my Jsbin example. In Firefox, the baseline of the button is the baseline of the last line of text that it contains, like an inline-block box, and in Chrome the baseline of the button is the baseline of the first line of text that it contains, like a table-cell box,

Comment: @Alohci Read that statement again, especially the last five words :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I see what you're saying. but I still don't think it's exactly right. The block-level internal box is centred vertically (according to the HTML5 spec). That will depend on the ascent and descent of the font, not the ex-height.