# Does adding a character inside a button change its height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(myBtn.innerHTML) {
        myBtn.innerHTML = ''
    } else {
        myBtn.innerHTML = 'x'
    }
})
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red">
  <button id="btn" style="height:50px;width:50px">  </button>
</div>
```

I am trying to build a tic-tac-toe game as a project. The problem is when I write a button, and on clicking it, adding an 'x' or 'o' inside it, the layout around it changes. This distorts my layout.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Is this the expected behavior of HTML?

I have created a small sample for the problem in the code above. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The height of the button doesn't change, but the layout based on it does: when text is not present in the button, there is some space below; when it is present, there is no space (the container hugs the button).

Comment: Aside: you can clean up that event listener code a lot. Get a reference to the button once, and use that. And, if you want, within the listener you can use `event.currentTarget` instead of the variable you saved the reference in (where `event` is the event, the first argument passed in); said property being a reference to the element the listener is attached to.

Comment: Thanks @DarrylNoakes, yes sorry for the oversight, the button remains the same, but the space around is changing. Why would that be? And is there some spec where all these behaviors are defined?

Comment: Yes, this will be in one of the layout-related specs, or at least as a consequence of behaviors defined in the specs. I don't work (incl. SO) on the weekend, so I'll only be able to look into it on Monday. However, I will say this: this issue almost certainly falls into the class of issues caused by the difference between no content vs text content. Lots of quirks there... It is possibly being treated differently regards line height / spacing, etc, as it is treated as either an empty element or as a text-containing element.

Comment: TL;DR from the duplicates: the baseline of an empty button is not the same as the baseline of a button with content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML == 'x') {
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML= '&nbsp;'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML= 'x'
  }
})
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red">
  <button id="btn" style="height:50px;width:50px">&nbsp;</button>
</div>
```

&nbsp;

Non-breaking Space, the "placeholder" no1, because html doesn't like empty tags.

Edit:

This behaviour is absolutely normal. The block element needs a text (or any other content with a real height) to determinate it's base height. You can achieve this by a workaround with css which isn't a real solution and doesn't work with all browsers.

Same happens e.g. in word doc with a empty line if change the size.
This is nothing "strange" and is as it's meant to be.

```html
<div style="background-color:red">Hello World</div>
<hr />
<div style="background-color:green">
   <div style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="background-color:green">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to solve it, thank you @7three, is this some documented behaviour?

Comment: @soumitra For sure. If you read any serious html guide, it should be on the first page, I think. At least for me many years ago. If you want to know more about chars look at a ASCII table like: https://www.ascii-code.com .

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend some serious guide for HTML? I find every HTML guide to be too scattered to learn. Where did you learn it from?

Comment: @soumitra Google for html guides, which have that char on the first page :P - Jokes aside: I'm not an IT professional, so I don't want to make any suggestions concerning "how-to learn" because I don't think it's appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a complete answer but a pointer to the actual problem and has a workaround in CSS rather than having to put in an otherwise unneeded character in the HTML.

The problem is related to the fact that the default for vertical-align is baseline.

Change that to say bottom and the space will go away.

It depends on how the browser decides where the ‘baseline’ is of the empty button. It seems to be treating it like a non replaced element with the given dimensions. Eg an img which will be aligned with the bottom of an x for example leaving space for descenders.

See  [stackoverflow.com/questions/68655937/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655937/) for further, albeit not totally conclusive, discussion of this.

Comment: You're wrong. The char is needed. You add many chars to css too ;)

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. Could you expand on what is meant by the char is needed?

Comment: Sigh. You suggest a unnecessary workaround in CSS which needs many many unnecessary characters instead of the one "to put in an otherwise unneeded character in the HTML".

Comment: Or as a doctor would say: you fight the symptoms and not the cause.